# R Markdown stopped previewing Latex equations

Tags: r, latex, markdown, equation

For some reason, Markdown stopped previewing equations put between `$$...$$` which it usually did automatically right underneath `$$equation$$`. It also stopped previewing inline equations between `$...$` when hovering above them with the cursor.

Restarting R did not solve this. Is this a known issue with a simple fix?

Comment: Where was the preview happening? Are you using RStudio? Or are you using the base R GUI?

Comment: Can you check your Rmarkdown global options? Like `tools > Global options > R markdown > show equation and image preview` ?

Comment: I am using R Studio and Markdown. Knitting works perfectly! ```tools > Global options > R markdown > show equation and image preview ``` is set to ```inline```

Comment: There is also a "Preview images and equations" option in the dropdown from the cog wheel next to knit. That option seems to work independently from the global options. Is that checked too? I had to uncheck it and check it to make it work after it went away.

Comment: @guasi that also did not work unfortunately